# Javascript "virtual browser"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm interested in "writing a browser UI" in javascript...which would run inside a REAL (native) browser.

I realize that Firefox/Opera/Chrome have thousands of "extensions" that extend and alter the UI, and for everything else there are Bookmarklets.  But that's not what I'm after.

This is what I'm after:

1. In Chrome/Firefox/whatever, I load up a regular HTML page with some Javascript code.
2. The code instantiates an Iframe called, say, MyBrowser.
3. Interacting with MyBrowser in JS is just like interacting with a real browser.
4. MyBrowser can load up any site or web app just like a real browser, and lets me interact with its GUI like normal.
5. At its simplest, the "regular HTML page" would just have the MyBrowser Iframe, an Input text field for the address, and two Buttons for forward and back.
6. But if I want to alter or extend any part of MyBrowser, I just write some JS/DOM code.

In other words, MyBrowser has all your regular JS browser API (including HTML5) features like:

```
window.history.back();
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
sessionStorage.setItem("username", "John");
```

It occurs to me that probably possible to write a "wrapper" by hand that works like this, but I'm curious if there is a codebase out there that could help simplify this project.

Comment: Would an iframe or a new browser window work?  If not, please explain more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why? I guess you can try emulating webkit in a browser

Comment: My own purpose would be to "make my own browser" with my own special features.  In other words, I could code my own browser UI/workflow in JS (and "run it inside" of Chrome/Firefox/whatever).

Comment: What does Chrome not do which your browser-within-a-browser would do?

Comment: 1000 things.  Chrome extensions, as the OP states, are not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking something like [Google Chrome Frame for IE](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) ?

Comment: No, this is completely unrelated to what I'm looking for.  I should have specified that I'm talking about basically a JS object that acts like a full-fledged browser.